# The use of "Nos." for multiple objects

Tags: abbreviations

I noticed a string on a similar question that is now closed; I would like your input on a specific problem that has puzzled me.

At my publishing company, people are fond of writing, e.g., "Law Nos. 1 through 5" to describe, collectively, five separate laws enumerated 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

To me, this seems incorrect.

Using "Nos." in the above manner seems, literally, to mean "Law Numbers 1 through 5", but the phrase "Law Nos. 1 through 5" does not describe one law with five different numbers, nor does it describe numbers in the abstract.  The intended reference is to five different laws that are separately enumerated.

Another way to express the matter in words is "Laws Numbered 1-5"; from this, it seems more correct to abbreviate the matter as "Laws No. 1-5".

I am curious about other ways to look at this problem.

Thanks and regards,

q.b.

Comment: "Laws 1-5" is what springs to mind...

Answer (score 1):

Nos. is an abbreviation for numbers. Consider the difference between "law numbers 1 through 5" and "laws numbered 1 through 5".

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  'Law' is the base (titular) noun.  'Numbered' is a passive adjective, and 'Number' is used as a proper noun (the name of the law).

Answer (score -1):

If the laws are important and the numbers only identify them then it's "laws numbered 1 through 5".  If it's the numbers that are important (eg, we're entering the list of numbers into a database) then it's "law numbers 1 through 5".  Abbreviate appropriately.